# Emulating scrollTop effect without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I was trying to emulate the scrollTop effect using JS. Here is the code I am using. This code was posted on SO as a part of another such question.

```
 function scrollToTop(element, to, duration){
        if(duration<0) return;
        var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
        var perTick = difference/duration * 10;
        console.log("Logging diff" +difference);
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(perTick);
            console.log("Log before scroll"+element.scrollTop);
            element.scrollTop=(element.scrollTop + perTick);
            console.log("Log after scroll"+element.scrollTop);
            scrollToTop(element, to, duration-10);
        }, 10);
        }
```

Now even though I am adding perTick to element.scrollTop, when console logs show that the addition doesnt take place.

```
 console.log("Log before scroll"+element.scrollTop);
```

and

```
 console.log("Log after scroll"+element.scrollTop);
```

both are showing 0. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Try `element.scrollTo(x,y);`

Comment: Is `perTick` greater than 0 when you print that in your console? Are your calculations working as expected?

Comment: @wongcode: Yes perTick is greater than 0.

Comment: @Passerby: http://jsfiddle.net/94V7u/ This is kinda that. I actually got rid of the code, since I got a working snippet online. But I would still like to know where I was going wrong. So any help would be great :)

Comment: @psyc0der Here's a version that kind of work, but with pitfalls: http://jsfiddle.net/94V7u/1/ The problem is: 1) `document.scrollTop` in your fiddle is undefined; 2) the use of `this` in your fiddle seems confusing (the `<a>` itself do not have `scrollTop`); 3) when `duration==0`, your function didn't return, so `perTick` is `NaN`, which lead to the last tick always scroll back to top.

Comment: Did you get your question answered? (If so, accept one?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different approach.  It works well, but I have questions -- I hope you do more with this and report back what you learn.  The scrolling is (seems?) smoothest with a 60ms delay.  I think this has to do with the 18ticks/sec clock?  The code is commented.  The function "lerp" (linear interpolation) is a useful function -- some languages have it native.  (I don't have enough points to comment.)

[edit] Interesing link: 
http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#buttons { position:fixed; left:100px; top:10px; }
#div1    { width:400px; height:100px; background:#eee; overflow:scroll; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function scrollto(elt, to, duration) { 
  if (duration < 0) return;
  console.log(to + " | " + elt.scrollHeight);
  if (to < 0 || to > elt.scrollHeight) return;
  var fm = elt.scrollTop;           // begin
  var time1 = new Date().getTime(); // begin
  var time9 = time1 + duration      // end
  scrollsub(elt, fm, to, time1, time9);
  }
function scrollsub(elt, fm, to, time1, time9) {
  console.log(fm + " | " + to + " | " + time1 + " | " + time9);
  var timenow = new Date().getTime();
  var k01 = (timenow - time1) / (time9 - time1);
  var whither = lerp(k01, fm, to);
  console.log(timenow + " | " + whither);
  if (timenow < time9) {
    elt.scrollTop = whither;
    setTimeout(scrollsub, 60, elt, fm, to, time1, time9); }
  else { elt.scrollTop = to; } // just finish
  }
function lerp(k01, k0, k1) { // linear interpolation
  return k0 + (k1 - k0) * k01; 
  }
function testgettime(time0, time) {
  var timenow = new Date().getTime() - time0;
  if (timenow != time) { 
    console.log(timenow/1000 + " | " + (timenow - time)/1000); }
  if (timenow < 2000) { // don't go forever 
    setTimeout(testgettime, 1, time0, timenow); }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodyid">
<div id="buttons">
  <button onclick="scrollto(getElementById('div1'), 150, 2000);">Scroll Down</button>
  <button onclick="scrollto(getElementById('div1'), 000, 2000);">Scroll Up</button>
  <button onclick="testgettime(new Date().getTime(), 0);">testgettime()</button>
</div>
x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />
<div id="div1">
y1<br />y2<br />y3<br />y4<br />y5<br />y6<br />y7<br />y8<br />y9<br />10<br />
</div>
x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />x<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```